# Logging to ULS from Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, logging, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to log to SharePoint 2010 ULS logs but I'm not having much success.
I have added a reference to `http://localhost/_vti_bin/Diagnostics.asmx`, I am working on the same machine where sharepoint is installed, to my Silverlight project and then I am using the following code

```
private void button1_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SharePointDiag.SharePointDiagnosticsSoapClient client = new SharePointDiag.SharePointDiagnosticsSoapClient();
        client.SendClientScriptErrorReportCompleted += new EventHandler<SharePointDiag.SendClientScriptErrorReportCompletedEventArgs>(sendComp);
        client.SendClientScriptErrorReportAsync("TEST", "TEST", 123, "TEST", "<client><browser name='Internet Explorer' version='9.0'></browser><language> en-us </language></client>"
            , "<stack><function depth='0' signature=' myFunction() '>function myFunction() { 'displaypage ();}</function></stack>", "TEST");
    }
```

The code is not giving an error or a result it just the completed event args are just null.
In Fiddler it looks like the calls are working correctly but when I check the logs in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS" my messages are not in them.

Any ideas or hints would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that one of the settings in the Central Admin wasn't set correctly. For some reason it will only log when the Least critical event is set to Information and not Verbose.